# Is there any framework or library alowing a deweloper push his pipe thru the NAT and recive it on back end as a pipe?

Tags: pipe, named-pipes, nat, nat-traversal

So I have an app on 1 pc creating a pipe, local pipe. I want to take it as a stream (like only last data in it or incoming data from it) and stream its data thru\over NAT (using nat traversal) to other pc somewhere ower NAT (so neather I or He has uniqe IP adress but we use nat traversal server\programm to comunicate) and there recive that data and create a new local pipe on that computer to other programms to use.

So I love C\C++\Java\C# but if there are libs in other languages I would love to learn that languages just for that lib!)

Is there any framework or library alowing a deweloper push his pipe thru the NAT and recive it on back end as a pipe?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [JXTA](http://jxse.kenai.com) as a potential solution?